# How do I fix the Players Rigidbody reaction when moving on two colliders? Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, rigid-bodies

The player bobs up when passing tiles with separate colliders (player with a capsule collider)
or just gets stuck on tile ends (player with a box collider)

I've seen fixes for similar issues in 2D but none in 3D

https://streamable.com/zbou2b

Comment: Have you tried reducing the `Default Contact Offset` in the Physics settings?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the default contact offset way lower than the lowest value the slider provides, that fixes it.